# Print success/finished message in user's own language

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I'd like to print a message to the user that indicates the script finished without issue. I know there's several localization-based functions, but instead of having to provide a list of machined translated strings, it would be better there was an internal list of common messages I could pull from (from .NET or wherever else) that would be locale-dependent. Or, maybe a built-in command that prints a success message.

Comment: `[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(0).Message` should give you whatever the local equivalent of "The operation completed successfully" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) from [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67946647/print-success-finished-message-in-users-own-language?noredirect=1#comment120098812_67946647):

> `[ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(0).Message` should give you
> whatever the local equivalent of "The operation completed
> successfully" is.

*(I'm not sure why he didn't submit it as an answer.)*

There are many more messages too. I've filtered out the 'Unknown errors' from the first 20,000:
https://pastebin.com/F9jQUHMt

Command used:

```
$m = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]'
(0..20000).ForEach({ try{$m.add((([ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new($_).
Message -join ' ') -replace '\s\s+',' '), $_)} catch{} })
$m.Keys.Where({$_ -notlike 'Unknown error *'}).ForEach({ "[$($m.Item($_))] $_" })
```

I used a dictionary so that only the first occurrence of an error message would be added along with its index. And, as far as I can tell, 15864 is the last non-unknown error.